# Bootstrap 3 - Espaçamento entre inputs

Tags: css, bootstrap-3

Estou construindo um `form` que em alguns momentos terá 3 colunas e mais de 4  linhas mas não estou conseguindo fazer que ao começar a nova linha o espaçamento entre os inputs seja respeitado, veja no bloco "Identificação do Campo de Produção", já tentei algumas alternativas e não resolveu, tentei algo como:

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

O form que tenho está assim:

```
  <div class="widget-body">
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Identificação do Responsável Técnico</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Agrônomo - Técnico *</label>
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Text field" type="text">
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Identificação do Produtor</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Nome *</label>
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Text field" type="text">
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Identificação do Campo de Produção</legend>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
        <label>ID *</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Text field">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9">
        <label>Cooperante *</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Text field">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
        <label>Zoom</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Text field">
      </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
        <label>Propriedade *</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Text field">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10">
        <label>Vistoria *</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Text field">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
        <label>UF *</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Text field">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10">
        <label>Município *</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Text field">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10">
        <label>Categoria *</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Text field">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
        <label>Campo *</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Text field">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Espécie *</label>
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Text field" type="text">
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

O que gera uma saída assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que preciso e não estou conseguindo, é isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por favor posta o seu CSS também

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na `div` que determina o tamanho ao adicionar o `form-control`, tem o resultado esperado, também foi retirado o `<br />` para ficar com a mesma distância:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="widget-body">
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Identificação do Responsável Técnico</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Agrônomo - Técnico *</label>
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Text field" type="text">
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Identificação do Produtor</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Nome *</label>
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Text field" type="text">
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Identificação do Campo de Produção</legend>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 form-group">
        <label>ID *</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Text field">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 form-group">
        <label>Cooperante *</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Text field">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 form-group">
        <label>Zoom</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Text field">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 form-group">
        <label>Propriedade *</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Text field">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 form-group">
        <label>Vistoria *</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Text field">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 form-group">
        <label>UF *</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Text field">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 form-group">
        <label>Município *</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Text field">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 form-group">
        <label>Categoria *</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Text field">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 form-group">
        <label>Campo *</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Text field">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Espécie *</label>
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Text field" type="text">
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

Assim resolvendo seu problema.

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado David pela grande ajuda, perfeito.

Answer (score 2):

Deve ser alguma classe não setada no html, abaixo tem um exemplo com a estrutura do bootstrap, ele já vem com margens e espaçamentos padronizados, segue exemplo:

```
  <h3>4 colunas</h3>    
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
     <div class="form-group">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<h3>3 colunas</h3>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
   <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<h3>2 colunas</h3>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<h3>1 coluna</h3>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```